# Elliptical Curve point addition and doubling on montgomery curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, python

I am trying to teach myself about elliptical curve cryptography using online resources, and have created a program to perform point addition and point doubling on a montgomery curve.
To test my function, I am calculating 4p using two methods: 2(2p) and p + p + p + p. To my understanding, the values should be equivalent, but I'm getting different values.

I'm using curve M-221 defined as:

`y^2 = x^3 + 117050 * x^2 + x` with field `2^221 - 3` and the generator point:

`{x: 1868095183606742538701435617698957211251810735713795112730238517387, y: 1432401617868315471469241676678456314840808294315547381535466705153}`

When running my test I get:

```
p4_double:   {'x': 1158296677984570086957317285562479367861170755348925863907217477275, 'y': 1551028763014061658160471452226999211325397814089364066655644963406}
p4_add:      {'x': 27500914413453982607377956096660382032281000528958526135014696542, 'y': 1168146124709862201096710659924046078056321465610616206479606975751}
--------------------------------------------------
p2:          {'x': 339504813444055524776350731343982961171002195927973873104309035752, 'y': 2932526515499324705932531354096697705273063568784183338538040616672}
p3:          {'x': 394721346804099203910004476506708200743020785679182057269678209841, 'y': 1663472166528890517288736425441643076121539170204221488121613770082}
```

My question is, what am I doing to make 2(2p) != p + p + p + p. I believe that my problem lies in one of the following:

- Incorrect mathematics (which is why I believe this question belongs here and not in crypto)
- use of rounding
- use of modulo

Interestingly, 2p and 4p_add are very similar, lending me to believe the error lies in adding two points. I appreciate all feedback, as I am very new to elliptical curves, and especially with working within finite fields.

Edit: So I found out that I needed to use modulo much more frequently throughout my program. I now have a function that works on small fields, but still fails the given curve.
Given these parameters the function works perfectly -  even having 16p_add and 16p_double coinciding:

```
curve = {
    "A": 5,
    "B": 3,
    "field": 65537,
    "generator": {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 5
    }
}
```

I therefore believe that the error is coming from python not keeping enough significant bits on large numbers. However, I would still love help to fix my program if the error lies elsewhere. (At this point this question may belong in a section dedicated to python/programming)
Here is my code:

```
# Provides elliptical-curve math capability for deffie-hellman key exchange

# The initial parameters for the montgomery curve: B * y^2 = x^3 + A * X^2 + x
# values obtained for curve M-221 (2013 Aranha–Barreto–Pereira–Ricardini)
# Generator point obtained from tutorial at: https://sage.math.clemson.edu:34567/home/pub/847/
curve = {
    "A": 117050,
    "B": 1,
    "field": 2 ** 221 - 3,
    "generator": {
        "x": 1868095183606742538701435617698957211251810735713795112730238517387,
        "y": 1432401617868315471469241676678456314840808294315547381535466705153
    }

}


def gcd_extended(a, b):
    """
    Uses Euclidean algorithm
    :param a: Int the value to test
    :param b: Int the modulo to use
    :return: x, y
    """
    if a == 0:
        return 0, 1
    x, y = gcd_extended(b % a, a)

    return y - (b // a) * x, x


def inverse_mod(a, b):
    """
    Calculates the inverse mod for a given a^-1 % b
    :param a: Int the value to find the inverse mod of
    :param b: Int the modulo to use
    :return: Int the inverse modulo
    """
    x, y = gcd_extended(a, b)
    # final modulo is to ensure x lies within the modulo field
    return x % b


def point_combination(_m, _p1, _p2):
    """
    Calculates p1 + p2 = p3 returning p3 - used by both doubling and adding functions
    I separated this function from the other two in hopes to make the code more readable
    :param _m: The slope of the line through p1, p2 or tangent line of p1
    :param _p1: Dictionary the first point given as {"x", "y"}
    :param _p2: Dictionary the first point given as {"x", "y"} or p1 if doubling
    :return: p3 as Dictionary {"x", "y"} within the curve field
    """

    # Calculate x, note that _p2["x"] == _p1["x"] if we are doubling
    # I round here to keep x as an int and take modulo field at this point
    x = (curve["B"] * _m ** 2 - (_p1["x"] + _p2["x"]) - curve["A"]) \
        % curve["field"]

    # Calculate y from x
    # I round here to keep y as an int and take modulo field at this point
    y = (_m * (_p1["x"] - x) - _p1["y"]) % curve["field"]

    # return p3 - note that initially we have R, so flip y along x axis for p3
    return {"x": x, "y": y}


def points_add(_p1, _p2):
    """
    Calculates p1 + p2 = p3 returning p3
    :param _p1: Dictionary the first point given as {"x", "y"}
    :param _p2: Dictionary the second point given as {"x", "y"}
    :return: p3 as Dictionary {"x", "y"} within the curve field
    """

    # Calculate the slope through points _p1 and _p2
    _m = (_p2["y"] - _p1["y"]) * inverse_mod(_p2["x"] - _p1["x"], curve["field"])

    # use slope and two points to find p3 and return it
    return point_combination(_m, _p1, _p2)


def point_double(_p):
    """
    Calculates p + p = 2p returning 2p
    :param _p: Dictionary the point to double given as {"x", "y"}
    :return: 2p as Dictionary {"x", "y"} within the curve field
    """

    # Calculate the tangent line using the derivative dx/dy
    _m = ((3 * _p["x"] ** 2 + 2 * curve["A"] * _p["x"] + 1) *
          inverse_mod(2 * curve["B"] * _p["y"], curve["field"])) % curve["field"]

    # use slope and the point to find p3 and return it
    # p is listed twice in this function, as the formula for x uses the x value of two points
    # in point doubling the second x value = p["x"]
    return point_combination(_m, _p, _p)


# just shorthand for the generator point
p = curve["generator"]

# calculate 4p via point doubling twice and adding p 4 times


# start with an initial doubling
p2 = point_double(p)

p4_double = point_double(p2)

p3 = points_add(p, p2)
p4_add = points_add(p, p3)

# in theory the values should be the same as 2 * 2p  ==  p + p + p + p = 2p + p + p
print("p4_double: \t", p4_double)
print("p4_add: \t", p4_add)

print("-" * 50)
print("p2: \t\t", p2)
print("p3: \t\t", p3)
```

Comment: @tonyK I understand that addition isn't the same as doubling, but then how would the shortcut method for calculating nP given n is large? From what I've read - which my understanding may be wrong - to calculate 57P, one may add P + 8P + 16P + 32P in order to skip repeated adding.
Edit: I may misunderstand, I start both calculations doubling P so I'm comparing 2(2p) and 2p + p + p

Comment: Found this document helpful for understanding the arithmetics on Montgomery Curves  https://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/68653.pdf ~ *Implementation of Elliptic
Curve25519 in Cryptography*

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my edit, I was able to successfully edit my function to work without any problems on a smaller curve, using the parameters:

```
curve = {
    "A": 5,
    "B": 3,
    "field": 65537,
    "generator": {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 5
    }
}
```

The two functions add and double are consistent to 2^14p, that is 14 doublings. After this point, the two values begin to deviate due to significant bit errors. I tried changing `B -> 1` and found the same error occurs after 2^14p.

The initial problem was that I needed to find the inverse modulo whenever I divided, instead of rounding after division.

At this point, there appears to be nothing wrong with the math.
Here is the final code for those who are curious:

````
# Provides elliptical-curve math capability for deffie-hellman key exchange

# The initial parameters for the montgomery curve: B * y^2 = x^3 + A * X^2 + x
# values obtained for curve M-221 (2013 Aranha–Barreto–Pereira–Ricardini)
# Generator point obtained from tutorial at: https://sage.math.clemson.edu:34567/home/pub/847/
# These particular values where taken from: 
# https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396544/problem-with-elliptic-curve-in-montgomery-form?rq=1
curve = {
    "A": 5,
    "B": 1,
    "field": 65537,
    "generator": {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 5
    }
}


def gcd_extended(a, b):
    """
    Uses Euclidean algorithm
    :param a: Int the value to test
    :param b: Int the modulo to use
    :return: x, y
    """
    if a == 0:
        return 0, 1
    x, y = gcd_extended(b % a, a)

    return y - (b // a) * x, x


def inverse_mod(a, b):
    """
    Calculates the inverse mod for a given a^-1 % b
    :param a: Int the value to find the inverse mod of
    :param b: Int the modulo to use
    :return: Int the inverse modulo
    """
    x, y = gcd_extended(a, b)
    # final modulo is to ensure x lies within the modulo field
    return x % b


def point_combination(_m, _p1, _p2):
    """
    Calculates p1 + p2 = p3 returning p3 - used by both doubling and adding functions
    I separated this function from the other two in hopes to make the code more readable
    :param _m: The slope of the line through p1, p2 or tangent line of p1
    :param _p1: Dictionary the first point given as {"x", "y"}
    :param _p2: Dictionary the first point given as {"x", "y"} or p1 if doubling
    :return: p3 as Dictionary {"x", "y"} within the curve field
    """

    # Calculate x, note that _p2["x"] == _p1["x"] if we are doubling
    x = (curve["B"] * _m ** 2 - (_p1["x"] + _p2["x"]) - curve["A"]) \
        % curve["field"]

    # Calculate y from x
    y = (_m * (_p1["x"] - x) - _p1["y"]) % curve["field"]

    return {"x": x, "y": y}


def points_add(_p1, _p2):
    """
    Calculates p1 + p2 = p3 returning p3
    :param _p1: Dictionary the first point given as {"x", "y"}
    :param _p2: Dictionary the second point given as {"x", "y"}
    :return: p3 as Dictionary {"x", "y"} within the curve field
    """

    # Calculate the slope through points _p1 and _p2
    # This is one location where inverese_mod was needed as we cannot simply find
    # (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) - since this is % field we need to multiply by inverse mod (x2-x1) 
    _m = (_p2["y"] - _p1["y"]) * inverse_mod(_p2["x"] - _p1["x"], curve["field"])

    # use slope and two points to find p3 and return it
    return point_combination(_m, _p1, _p2)


def point_double(_p):
    """
    Calculates p + p = 2p returning 2p
    :param _p: Dictionary the point to double given as {"x", "y"}
    :return: 2p as Dictionary {"x", "y"} within the curve field
    """

    # Calculate the tangent line using the derivative dy/dx
    # Another location where we need to use inverse_mod as dy/dx % field ->
    # dy * inverse_mod(dx)
    _m = ((3 * _p["x"] ** 2 + 2 * curve["A"] * _p["x"] + 1) *
          inverse_mod(2 * curve["B"] * _p["y"], curve["field"])) % curve["field"]

    # use slope and the point to find p3 and return it
    # p is listed twice in this function, as the formula for x uses the x value of two points
    # in point doubling the second x value = p["x"]
    return point_combination(_m, _p, _p)


# just shorthand for the generator point
p = curve["generator"]

# calculate 4p via point doubling twice and adding p 4 times


# start with an initial doubling
p2 = point_double(p)
# 2^n will be the value (2^n)P to find
n = 14

# For the doubling function
pn_pow = p2
for i in range(n-1):
    pn_pow = point_double(pn_pow)
    print(f"p{2 ** (i + 1)}: \t\t", pn_pow)

# for the adding
pn_add = p2
for i in range(2 ** n - 2):
    pn_add = points_add(p, pn_add)

# the values are equivalent to (2^14)p and deviate by (2^15)p
print(f"p{2 ** n}_double: \t", pn_pow)
print(f"p{2 ** n}_add:    \t", pn_add)

```
````

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to use already written code. [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org) is the canonical choice, elliptic curve operations are supported in an object oriented way, the code is python "with batteries" (finally performing operations in other computer algebra systems like pari/gp).

Here is all what is needed to compute $4P$ either as $P+P+P+P$, or as $2(2P)$ in the given example.

To initialize a curve defined by $y^2 +a_1xy +a_3 y = x^3 + a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$ just pass the list $[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_6]$ to the constructor as below. (If the curve has $a_1=a_3=a_2=0$, then one can pass simply $[s_4,a_6]$ instead. This is not the case for our curve $M-221$, but it is good to know.) The code and the computation, as shown in the IPython console is as follows...

---

```
F = GF(2^221 - 3) 
E = EllipticCurve(F, [0, 117050, 0, 1, 0])
x0 = 1868095183606742538701435617698957211251810735713795112730238517387
y0 = 1432401617868315471469241676678456314840808294315547381535466705153
P = E.point( (x0, y0) )    # and the point is also checked
P + P + P + P == 2*(2*P)
```

The last line delivers...

```
sage: P + P + P + P == 2*2*P
True
sage: P + P + P + P == 4*P
True
```

And the point is

```
sage: Q = 4*P    # its components are - in case Q is not (0:1:0)
sage: Q.xy()[0]  # first component, x component of Q
1158296677984570086957317285562479367861170755348925863907217477275
sage: Q.xy()[1]  # second component, y component of Q
1551028763014061658160471452226999211325397814089364066655644963406
```

Since the library is free, and the whole involved code is accessible, it may be a good idea to just import it...

Comment: Thank you for the link to the sage library. Unfortunately, the aim of this project is to understand how to use elliptical curve cryptography, rather than relying on another's understanding. I wanted to learn how it worked, and model it with my own implementations of the equations. I was able to figure out my program last week, and will post the changes I needed to make, and what my error was.

Comment: The above was (also) rather a way to help you find the error. You had in the initial post two different answers for the two different ways mentioned to compute $4P$, the one was leading to `p4_double`, the other one to `p4_add`. Since there was hard to see how you could obtain the two values from the posted question by simply following the code, and writing formulas - as extracted from the code, without a conceptual meaning. The explicit question was: "*what am I doing to make 2(2p) != p + p + p + p*" - my answer tells that the addition was wrong. It is really hard to digest your code...